# What is the Time Complexity for In-Place Quick sort?

Tags: quicksort

I know the space complexity decreases from O(n) to O(log n). But what about the Time complexity? Does it take the same time to execute as regular version of Quick Sort?

Answer (score 0):

Quicksort IS a recursive inplace sorting algorithm, what do you mean with this question?
There is not a non-inplace version of quicksort.
Since it is a recursive divide-et-impera algorithm is easy to show that as you say space complexity is at least O(log n). It can be less as noted if you use the iterative implementation, space compleity will be O(1).

The complexity of the algorithm is averaged O(n log n), is O(n*n) worst case in the default implementation. The worst case is when the list is already sorted.

Merge sort, instead, is O(n log n) worst case, is however usually slower than quicksort due to big constants.
Also merge sort have a space complexity of O(log n).

Comment: For example, if we are using arrays for Quick sort, then in-place Quick sort will use the same array to store values and not create new arrays for further storage thus reducing space complexity. So for this procedure, will it take the same time as Quick sort does?

Comment: Quick sort is just in-place, it sorts an input array in place without producing an output array. To sort an input array to output array you need to copy it first and then sort the copied array.

Answer (score 0):

There exists QuickSort implementations that runs on O(nlogn) worst-case, and as for your question, there is no better then O(nlogn) worst case comparison based sort, and as quick sort is 1, it is proved that O(nlogn) is cant be beaten anyway.

the only implementation of QuickSort i know is in-place but anyhow all you can improve is quicksort's constants, other then that is what you mentioned, the space required can be reduced to O(1) (iterative version), and O(logn) in the recursive version.

Comment: So you mean to say that if we use the in place version .i.e. the Quick sort version that utilizes the same array over and over again to store data instead of creating new ones thus reducing space, the best, worst and average cases will be same if we use the Quick sort version that creates new arrays each time it needs to store data.

Comment: creating new arrays is very naive, but the answer is yes, you still are running O(n) in every iteration.